# Extract specific string from a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below pyspark dataframe.

```
column_a
name,age,pct_physics,country,class
name,age,pct_chem,class
pct_math,class
```

I have to extract only the part of string which begins with only pct and discard rest of them.

Expected output:

```
column_a
pct_physics
pct_chem
pct_math
```

How to achieve this in pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`regexp_extract`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract) function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("output",regexp_extract(col("column_a"),"(pct_.*?),",1)).show(10,False)
#+----------------------------------+-----------+
#|column_a                          |output     |
#+----------------------------------+-----------+
#|name,age,pct_physics,country,class|pct_physics|
#|name,age,pct_chem,class           |pct_chem   |
#+----------------------------------+-----------+
```